# Is Loki part of a destiny trap?

Tags: marvel, paradox, doctor-strange, loki

In Doctor Strange #385 Loki admits that he wanted to make Dr. Strange stronger for the threads to come, e.g. Damnation. However, in Doctor Strange: Damnation #1 it is established that Doctor Strange (a) causes Damnation (in an act that was very stupid, he was probably high on power) and (b) only could do so because Loki made him acquire more power. At the moment we cannot know what Loki knows or how he knows it, but the situation seems very paradox to me. Also Strange still seems unaware that this is part of what Loki warned him about. **EDIT:** In issue #387 some form of subconscious image of Loki Stephen has himself points out that this is what he warned him about. So in a way, Strange realized by now.

In Doctor Who's episode "The Time of the Doctor" the Doctor (not Strange) says “The destiny trap. You can’t change history if you’re part of it.” upon how a part of an organization went back in time to avoid a series of events, only to become part of the cause. I wonder if this applies to Loki as well.

**Question:** Is Loki part of a paradox he is unable to change, or are there other reasonable explanations?

I think it would be very hard to know about what Damnation is (which I assume is true for Loki, since he considers it a threat) and not recognize that a powerful wizard did it. In other terms, I think Loki is too intelligent not to know that Stephen will cause it.

Comment: Are you asking about whether Loki fits the parameters of something established in a completely different work of fiction? Or are you simply asking whether the intent in the Marvel universe is that Loki can't fight fate?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It is not "established" in a completely different work of fiction, it is merely named there and I thought the name was fitting; in addition in my *Question* itself I didn't mentioned the destiny trap but wrote "paradox he is unable to change". Rephrasing the question in your words: "Can Loki not fight fate or are there other explanations." But "fate" seems like a word to strong here, especially since Malekith just recently killed the Queen of Nirns. We don't now the exact chronology yet, but it is something Loki would know and regarding his nature he would challenge fate then.

Comment: I wanted to be certain. :) Sometimes, when people use specific terms, they want specific interpretations. Just to clarify, are you asking whether it was inevitable, or whether there is evidence that someone made it inevitable by setting up the situation so no matter what Loki did, it would end as it did? I've seen the latter described as a "Destiny Trap" as well, I think in Stross's "Laundry Files" books.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No problem. I'm new here, so I'm not really used to the average customs of question intention yet :) Regarding your question, it doesn't matter. I think this is Marvel's annual foreshadowing event. The last one was with Spiderman and a zodiac villian group, where the leader of the latter obtained knowledge of a whole year before he was put out of commission. He predicted Secret Empire, among other things. Regarding your question, I'm interested in both possibilities. Loki tricked the Shi'ar gods, so who could possibly trick Loki? (Apart from Hank Pym of course ;) )